# JS runned twice doesn't work

Tags: javascript, onclick, radio-button, label

I have on a page an input (radio button) and its label. To this label is onClick attached to make possible to set the radio with clicking on the label. If i have such thing once on the page is everything ok, but if i have radio+label twice, so the clicking onto second label sets the first radion. The code looks so:

```
   <input id="shipping_<?php echo $rate['element']; ?>" name="shipping_plugin" rel="<?php echo $rate['name']; ?>" type="radio" value="<?php echo $rate['element'] ?>" onClick="k2storeSetShippingRate('<?php echo $rate['name']; ?>','<?php echo $rate['price']; ?>',<?php echo $rate['tax']; ?>,<?php echo $rate['extra']; ?>, '<?php echo $rate['code']; ?>', true );" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
   <label for="shipping_<?php echo $rate['element']; ?>" onClick="k2storeSetShippingRate('<?php echo $rate['name']; ?>','<?php echo $rate['price']; ?>',<?php echo $rate['tax']; ?>,<?php echo $rate['extra']; ?>, '<?php echo $rate['code']; ?>', true );"><?php echo $rate['name']; ?> ( <?php echo K2StorePrices::number( $rate['total']); ?> )</label>
```

I'm happy about any advice how to run this onClick thing so, that the second occurrence sets correct, own radio.

Thanks!
Egon

Comment: You don't have to put a "click" handler on a label that's bound to an input. The handler on the input will fire when the label is clicked.

Comment: The weird thing is, if i delete the onClick for the label and label looks like  <label for="shipping_<?php echo $rate['element']; ?>">test</label>, the click onto label of the second radio sets the first radio!

Answer (score 0):

Input and label must be formatted as following code:

```
<label><input id="shipping_<?php echo $rate['element']; ?>" name="shipping_plugin" rel="<?php echo $rate['name']; ?>" type="radio" value="<?php echo $rate['element'] ?>" onClick="k2storeSetShippingRate('<?php echo $rate['name']; ?>','<?php echo $rate['price']; ?>',<?php echo $rate['tax']; ?>,<?php echo $rate['extra']; ?>, '<?php echo $rate['code']; ?>', true );" <?php echo $checked; ?> >&nbsp;<?php echo $rate['name']; ?></label>
```